# angular check if scroll was triggered manually or from script

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working with Angular 7, and I have a directive that listens to the scrolling of an element. The problem is, that I want the directive to respond only to manual scrolls, and ignore programmatic scrolls done with `element.scrollTop = x`.
The directive contains a scroll listener, like so:

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll($event) {
  }
```

In one of the places in my code I set a programmatic scrollTop as described above, and an event was caught by the listener. I tried to find a property on `$event` that would indicate whether the event was manual or not, but couldn't find one. Did I miss it? Or perhaps that I can somehow trigger a custom event in vanilla javascript that would contain such indication (I know that in jQuery you can do that, but I'm not using jQuery here...). Thanks.

Comment: Since you are the one performing the programmatic scroll, you could set a variable in that point or you could add a getter for the `scrollTop` property

Answer (score 2):

Just add a flag and set it to false before you manual scroll.

Don't forget to set the flag back to true in your scroll handler

```
private handleScroll = true;

@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll($event) {
  if (!this.handleScroll) {
    this.handleScroll = true;
    return;
  }
}

public manualScroller() {
  this.handleScroll = false;

  this.element.scrollTop = 100;
}
```

Comment: Did you check my answer at all? 
manualScroller method will set a flag to false so scroll handler will check if that flag is false it will return

Comment: @messerbill,  OG has posted only his scroll handler. Why do you think I should know who and when should call manualScroller? It is a method to manually scroll the content and set a flag so onScroll method will check if it is a manual scroll or from code. Your downvote and comment makes no sense 
 therefore feel free to create more accounts to downvote

Comment: Well, your response does not answer the question that OP asked at all. He is asking how to detect if the scroll was manual or programmatic (done from .ts).